# Running a function to mirror an image in python

Tags: python, jes, jython-2.5

I keep trying to run this function:

```
def flipPic():
    #Set up source picture
    barbf=getMediaPath("barbara.jpg")
    barb=makePicture(barbf)
    #Now, for the mirroring
    mirrorPoint=219
    for X in range(0,mirrorPoint):
        for Y in range(0,291):
            pleft=getPixel(barb,X,Y)
            pright=getPixel(barb,Y,mirrorPoint + mirrorPoint - 1 - X)
            setColor(pright,(getColor(pleft)))
    show(barb)
    return(barb)
```

However, an error comes up on this line:

```
barb=makePicture(barbf)
```

It says:

> Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
>   An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.

I'm not sure what the issue is as it is written the same way that is in my textbook.
I am still learning how to program in python, is there something I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add as a tag the library that you are using.

Comment: I'm using jython in a program called jes(Jython Environment for Students).

Comment: I'm new to this site, what do you mean by library?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198166/whats-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-library-in-python) question.  What I want is just for you to say what you are using to accomplish this.  That is, what module or collection of modules are you using to manipulate your images?

Comment: Found the issue. The program was looking in the wrong folder for the images. Once I fixed that, the program worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what library you are using but this is a simple call in [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/index.html). The commands are these:

```
    out = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    out = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)
```

Taken from this chapter in the [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html#transposing-an-image).