# Difference between Module and Class in Python

Tags: python, class, python-module, class-hierarchy

Can I assign value to a variable in the module? If yes, what is the difference between a class and module?

PS: I'm a Java guy (in case it helps in the way of explaining). Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- **Module**:

  > A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.

As the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) say.

So a module in python is simply a way to organize the code, and it contains either python classes or just functions.
If you need those classes or functions in your project, you just `import` them.
For instance, the `math` module in python contains just a bunch of functions, and you just call those needed (`math.sin`).
Just have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198449/5386668).

On the other hand a python class is something similar to a java class, it's only structured in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 60):

There are *huge* differences between classes and modules in Python.

Classes are blueprints that allow you to create instances with attributes and bound functionality. Classes support inheritance, metaclasses, and descriptors.

Modules can't do any of this, modules are essentially *singleton instances* of an internal `module` class, and all their globals are attributes on the `module` instance. You can manipulate those attributes as needed (add, remove and update), but take into account that these still form the global namespace for all code defined in that module.

From a Java perspective, classes are not all that different here. Modules can contain more than just one class however; functions and any the result of any other Python expression can be globals in a module too.

So as a general ballpark guideline:

- Use classes as blueprints for objects that model your problem domain.
- Use modules to collect functionality into logical units.

Then store data where it makes sense to your application. Global state goes in modules (and functions and classes are just as much global state, loaded at the start). Everything else goes into other data structures, including instances of classes.

Comment: Coming from java to python I have been struggling a bit to grasp some of the concepts and I keep trying to relate everything back to java. This has been very helpful in clearing up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 15):

In python world, `module` is a `python` file (.py) inside a `package`. Package is a folder that has `__init__.py` in its root. It is a way to organize your codes **physically** (in files and folders).

On the other hand, `class` is an abstraction that gathers `data` (characteristics) and `method` (behavior) definitions to represent a specific type of objects. It is a way to organize your codes **logically**.

A module can have zero or one or multiple classes. A class can be implemented in one or more .py files (modules).

But often, we can organize a set of variables and functions into a class definition or just simply put them in a .py file and call it a module.

Likewise in system design, you can have elaborate logical modeling or just skip it and jump into physical modeling. But for very complex systems, it is better not to skip the logical modeling. For simpler systems, go KISS.

#### How to organize your code

This is how I decide to organize my code in classes or modules:

Class is supposed to be a blueprint to create (many) instances of objects based on that blueprint. Moreover, classes can have sub-classes (inheritance).

Therefore, if I need inheritance or (many) instantiations, I gather functions and variables under a class definition (methods and properties).

Otherwise, I Keep It Simple and Stupid (KISS) and use modules.

A good indication of a bad class (that should have been a module): you can rewrite all your `object methods and properties` with `static methods and properties`.

Answer (score 9):

Can I assign value to a variable in the module?
In short yes.

---

The concept of `module` refers to a single Python file which can be imported (by importing, you have the access to the variables/methods/classes defined in that module).

It is commonly discussed together with the concept `package`, which is a folder with `__init__.py`. A package can contain sub-packages or modules, and at the same time, similar to modules, can define variables/methods/classes to be imported inside its `__init__.py`.

The purpose of having modules/packages in Python is kind of similar to having packages in Java: to contain and categorize reusable codes, to resolve naming confliction and so on.

---

Besides, Python also has a builtin class named `module`, just like `list`, `tuple`, `dict` (note that Python builtin classes do not follow the CapWords naming convention due to legacy reasons). A `module` instance represents the module/package imported.

When you use the `import` statement to import a module (single Python file) or a package (folder with `__init__.py`), typically
1. a new instance of `module` class will be created
2. the classes/methods/variables you defined in that imported Python file will be added as the attributes of this `module` instance (if it is a package, it will be the classes/methods/variables defined in `__init__.py` that are added).

Therefore, since it is just an instance of `module` class, you can assign a value to the attribute of that instance and other class instance operations.

```
import math

print(type([1,2,3]))
print(type(math))
print(dir([1,2,3]))
print(dir(math))
```

console:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'module'>
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 'hypot', 'inf', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'log2', 'modf', 'nan', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'tau', 'trunc']
```

Answer (score 2):

It is like a concept: Module > Class > Function in Python. Here is an example of the usage of this idea in unit test tool, [Pytest about Fixture Scope across Classes, Modules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session).