# Does a module in Python act as a java object

Tags: python

I'm new to python so please just don't blast me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel('sepal length [cm]')
```

I know that the import works with modules and I also know what I module is.
The fact is that when a call the **xlabel** method same information is stored in **plt** as it would act as an object. In fact, if I then call

```
plt.show()
```

It appears a graph with **"sepal length [cm]"** in the x-axis.

So when I import a module it acts like an object? Is there a more precise definition of this?

Answer (score 1):

*Everything* in Python is an object (`1` is an object, not a special primitive type like in Java, classes are objects, functions are objects, etc.). Modules are just objects of the `module` type (which you never instantiate directly, it's just created implicitly when a module is imported), and their attributes are the globally defined names within the module.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, modules can feel like objects, since the functions can modify state in the module. There are important differences, however. For one, you can't make new instances. Importing a module again will just act like another name for the existing module. For instance, this will show the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2
plt1.plot([1, 2, 1])
plt2.show()
```

So there is always only one state per module, as far as I understand.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183244/difference-between-module-and-class-in-python).

Comment: Actually, the caching behavior for modules can be explicitly overridden to import a module more than once. It's a terrible idea, but it can be done, you just delete the entry for the module in `sys.modules` then `import` it again, and you get a separate copy.

Comment: @ShadowRanger the "how to 'impress' your colleagues" methodology :)

Comment: Well you can instantiate a module object, sort of, but whether you *should* is another matter.  `import sys` (or any other module) then `y = type(sys)('y')` where `y` is the new module object, but I have no idea why you would want to do that.