# module.function() vs object.method() in Python. Are they the same?

Tags: python, function, oop, object, import

I'm a **Java** guy, and I always used to think about the import keyword as a command to importing external classes and methods (packages)...

In Python I saw that it is slightly different... here you can use *import* to add some code and functions from another file and even add some classes from another file...

So when you want to execute a function from a file.py you have to write:

```
import file
file.function()
```

And if you want to execute a method from a class in class.py you have to write:

```
import class
object = class()
object.method()
```

My little java mind can't understand why do they have the same syntax... **does it mean that when you create an external file with some function you are unknowingly creating an object?**

Or the python team has just used the same keyword and syntax for two different scopes?

*Sorry if I wrote some incorrect concepts, I just tried to explain it easily*

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module, it is added to the programs `symbol table`. A symbol table is a `dict` that stores necessary information about the current program/file and is used by the compiler. To illustrate this, we can create two separate files:

```
# main.py

import file
```

```
# file.py

x = 25

def func():
    pass
```

In `main.py`, when you say `import file`, a separate namespace is created and added to the local symbol table of `main.py`. This is the reason for the syntax where you must say `file.x` or `file.func()`. To view the local symbol table, write `print(locals())` in `main.py`. As stated before, the symbol table is a dictionary. That means you can access elements inside of the symbol table by key. For example, in `main.py`:

```
print(locals()['file'])

# <module 'file' from 'path/to/file.py'>
```

If you don't want the entirety of `file.py` to be imported, you can use the `from/import` syntax. In `main.py`, replace `import file` with:

```
from file import x
```

As you can probably guess, `x` is added to the local symbol table of `main.py`. Now, you don't have to use `file.x` to access it - in fact, that will throw an error because the compiler doesn't know what `file` is.

```
print(x)

# 25
```

Modules and classes are completely different. A great explanation of the difference between classes and modules is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183993/12326283).