# jQuery - Library or Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is jquery a javascript library or framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062775/is-jquery-a-javascript-library-or-framework)

jQuery: The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript **Library**.

Why do people call it a framework when it clearly isn't? Also, why does jQuery call itself a library and Mootools calls itself a framework?

I'm in a debate. Mootools, jQuery, Prototype, they are libraries. Are they not?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and other similar JavaScript **libraries** (my opinion on that one) blur the line between library and framework because they in some or all instances override the DOM functionality in a similar fashion to the way that modern application development frameworks override the default APIs on other platforms.

The are still libraries, but they are robust enough that you can treat them like a framework and never work with the underlying API (in this instance, the DOM).

Comment: In fact jQuery does *not* override DOM methods. The original functions stay intact.

Comment: Yes, of course that's true but there are many people who never interact with the DOM because jQuery provides everything they need. And then when they need something jQuery can't do, they come here. :p