# what is the difference between a framework and a platform

Tags: frameworks

I know that a framework sets the foundation for a programming type but what is a programming platform? and if it is different to a framework how does it differ?

Comment: Google. http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?229460-Framework-VS-Development-Platform

Answer (score 46):

Typically, "platform" refers to the actual hardware/software upon which a piece of software is built or for which it is destined.
Example usage: "I built this app for the Windows platform."

"Framework" refers to a collection of libraries/classes with the common goal of providing a scaffold on which to build software. Frameworks might completely alter how you implement your program or they might just speed up common tasks.
Example usage: "I built this app using an MVC framework for the backend."

Example of using both terms together: "I built this app for  Android platform devices using Xamarin, an implementation of the .NET framework."

Comment: Applying your knowledge, what is .NET?

Comment: I think .NET is both framework and platform. By .NET, I mean .NET Core, .NET Framework, Mono, or Xamarin as opposed to .NET Standard, which is something totally different. I've written a [blog post](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/299/what-is-net-framework-or-platform) that discusses this.