# Difference between library, platform and framework?

Tags: frameworks, platform

I have come across the terms `framework`, `library`, `platform`. For example, we say `Spring framework` and NOT `Spring library`; as also we say `Java Platform` and NOT `Java Library` or `Java Framework`.

I tried to do understand further online, but the difference in them isn't still clear. Can anyone help me understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Library is just a set of tools for you to use. It won't normally enforce a workflow on you and your code will be executing library code. Math is a good example of a library.

Framework enforces workflow as it is a working thing and only gives you extension points to put your code in and it will run your code and control things for you. For example you have no control when spring framework will call your controller. You are given guidelines on what you need to do for Spring to think your class is a controller.

The platform defines a standard around which a system can be developed. It will have a set of standard APIs that expose specific components (streams, file system, ports, etc) for your use. JVM is a good example of a platform as well as operating systems.

Comment: Nice answer :) but few questions I have What is the workflow exactly mean in your answer, could you please brief it.

Comment: Workflow  here would be more in sense of code or component execution. Tools in libraries rarely require you follow specific order of steps. It is typical for frameworks. A web framework for example will make decisions for you on how to route request url to a specific controller, when to register middleware, etc. you just plug in your code to be executed by framework when certain events happen.