# What is the technical difference between CreateJS, JQuery & GreenSock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, createjs, gsap

As someone who is just now moving from ActionScript development into JavaScript development, I'm looking at various frameworks that can give me some of the animation power and flexibility that I'm used to.  I'm a bit confused by all the various options that are out there.

I'm currently using CreateJS because of the CreateJS Toolkit that is built into Flash, to help me port some of my work into JavaScript.

Are JQuery and GreenSock TweenMax competitors to CreateJS?  Are they complimentary? Are they entirely unrelated?

Thanks.  I feel embarrassed to be asking these n00b questions, but it is what it is.

Comment: First figure out exactly what each one is. jQuery for example is a library, not a framework. generally comparing a library to a framework is like comparing apples to oranges. comparing a javascript library to a flash library is madness.

Comment: @KevinB, could you please be constructive by explaining the technical difference between a library and a framework?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, though rather than re-inventing the wheel i'll just link to one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057526/framework-vs-toolkit-vs-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CreateJS is a framework that uses several libraries for a more fully-featured, pre-packaged app building experience. This is probably a good thing if you come from an ActionScript/Flash environment as it will be somewhat familiar.

Greensock TweenMax specifically competes with a section of CreateJS's framework, namely TweenJS, and targets post-Flash developers in a similar. TweenMax does offer a useful amount of features and is actually quite fast, though I've only tooled around with it briefly.

Jquery is a library for DOM manipulation/event handling/ *simple* animation (think, ease in a box, animate on mouseover, etc)/ AJAX. Jquery is incredibly popular and exists on [over 50% of websites](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/js-jquery/all/all). However, this solution isn't specifically focused on making animation-heavy applications like games, etc. For smoothing over cross-browser issues and adding some power and fluidity to common actions (DOM/AJAX/events), it's hard to beat.

Answer (score -4):

I worked a lot with AS and I think the best solution for you is HTMl5+CSS3+JS/JQUERY.
Regards :)

Comment: I'm sorry, Vitor, but we want facts, not opinions here. Why do you think that this particular combination is the best for the asker?

Comment: @Vitor Venturin, thanks for sharing your subjective opinion.  I do find it helpful.  Could you tell me how you use this combination?  What kind of development work is it helpful for and why?  Thank you.

Comment: `HTMl5+CSS3+JS/JQUERY: All websites use that!`