# Spring Swagger UI: what is difference between io.swagger, io.springfox, and com.mangofactory

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am working on integrating the swagger UI with a spring boot MVC app and I am curious as to the differences between these libraries.

I looked at each on mvnrepository.com and they are all done by different groups but seem to do the same thing. I am hoping to get a clear idea of the differences between these and if one is recommended over the others. I notice the swagger-core module by io.swagger has the most usages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`io.swagger` is the package for swagger libraries and you need separate spring jars to couple it with Spring. This is version 2 of swagger.

`io.springfox` is `Springfox` Swagger2, wherein swagger comes integrated with Spring.

`com.mangofactory` is swagger integrated with Spring Web MVC framework.

To understand differences between Spring Web MVC framework and spring, you can read this: 
[what is the difference between Spring and Spring MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320747/what-is-the-difference-between-spring-and-spring-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 7):

Here is [an explanation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#q2) of the different libraries.

Springfox is in a sense v2 of the swagger library that used to be packaged as `mangofactory`. What happened was we transitioned from using a private repo to creating a github organization so support development as a team.

In short `mangofactory` evolved into `springfox` which supports 2.0 version of swagger spec (in addition to 1.2). To be clear springfox and its predecessor supports spring mvc.

`io.swagger` is the *mother ship* if you will. It has great support for spring and jax-rs. So if you're looking for support for Jax-rs based services using spring or otherwise that's a great option.

Comment: Hi. Could you point out some documentation on how to filter API operations based on roles? SwaggerSpecFilter doesn't exist in Springfox Swagger, and I can't find a way to analyzed the roles and display only those operations which can be accessed for the user's granted roles.

Comment: Something that is currently left out in the linked explanation is that Swagger - the spec - is now called OpenAPI.