# Invoking methods in python

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, methods, pygame

I'm learning python from a beginners book. Below is an extract of code from that book (Python Programming for the absolute beginner, 3rd edition) for a game.
My question is a fairly simple one. The update() methods appear never to be invoked, yet still function. How does this work?
I've pasted the whole block of code, so nothing is missing.

```
# Pizza Panic
# Player must catch falling pizzas before they hit the ground

from livewires import games, color
import random

games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)


class Pan(games.Sprite):
    """
    A pan controlled by player to catch falling pizzas.
    """
    image = games.load_image("pan.bmp")

    def __init__(self):
        """ Initialize Pan object and create Text object for score. """
        super(Pan, self).__init__(image = Pan.image,
                                  x = games.mouse.x,
                                  bottom = games.screen.height)

        self.score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black,
                                top = 5, right = games.screen.width - 10)
        games.screen.add(self.score)

    def update(self):
        """ Move to mouse x position. """
        self.x = games.mouse.x

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width

        self.check_catch()

    def check_catch(self):
        """ Check if catch pizzas. """
        for pizza in self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.score.value += 10
            self.score.right = games.screen.width - 10 
            pizza.handle_caught()


class Pizza(games.Sprite):
    """
    A pizza which falls to the ground.
    """ 
    image = games.load_image("pizza.bmp")
    speed = 1   

    def __init__(self, x, y = 90):
        """ Initialize a Pizza object. """
        super(Pizza, self).__init__(image = Pizza.image,
                                    x = x, y = y,
                                    dy = Pizza.speed)

    def update(self):
        """ Check if bottom edge has reached screen bottom. """
        if self.bottom > games.screen.height:
            self.end_game()
            self.destroy()

    def handle_caught(self):
        """ Destroy self if caught. """
        self.destroy()

    def end_game(self):
        """ End the game. """
        end_message = games.Message(value = "Game Over",
                                    size = 90,
                                    color = color.red,
                                    x = games.screen.width/2,
                                    y = games.screen.height/2,
                                    lifetime = 5 * games.screen.fps,
                                    after_death = games.screen.quit)
        games.screen.add(end_message)


class Chef(games.Sprite):
    """
    A chef which moves left and right, dropping pizzas.
    """
    image = games.load_image("chef.bmp")

    def __init__(self, y = 55, speed = 2, odds_change = 200):
        """ Initialize the Chef object. """
        super(Chef, self).__init__(image = Chef.image,
                                   x = games.screen.width / 2,
                                   y = y,
                                   dx = speed)

        self.odds_change = odds_change
        self.time_til_drop = 0

    def update(self):
        """ Determine if direction needs to be reversed. """
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        elif random.randrange(self.odds_change) == 0:
           self.dx = -self.dx

        self.check_drop()


    def check_drop(self):
        """ Decrease countdown or drop pizza and reset countdown. """
        if self.time_til_drop > 0:
            self.time_til_drop -= 1
        else:
            new_pizza = Pizza(x = self.x)
            games.screen.add(new_pizza)

            # set buffer to approx 30% of pizza height, regardless of pizza speed   
            self.time_til_drop = int(new_pizza.height * 1.3 / Pizza.speed) + 1      


def main():
    """ Play the game. """
    wall_image = games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = wall_image

    the_chef = Chef()
    games.screen.add(the_chef)

    the_pan = Pan()
    games.screen.add(the_pan)

    games.mouse.is_visible = False

    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

# start it up!
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a *framework* `livewires` which you have imported at the top. That framework takes your `objects` and then invokes methods on them, instead of you calling the methods.

See this for a high level view of the difference between Frameworks and Libraries: [Framework vs. Toolkit vs. Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057526/framework-vs-toolkit-vs-library)

Comment: So was it an unnecessary step to invoke `self.check_catch()` (in the Pan class) for example?

Comment: @STATER No, it was necessary. There are only specific _parts_ of your code which the framework will call, not _all_ of them. These parts form the so called **application logic**, which makes one program written with the framework different from other programs.

Comment: Yes. I've found it in the livewires framework. Should have been mentioned in the notes by the author, especially since its a book for 'absolute beginners'. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The update() methods of each objects are called by the game module you are importing at the top:

```
from livewires import games, color
```

The GUI that these modules are handling runs in a loop that manages events and callbacks.

If you are curious, you could open load and read these files, and find out how the code works. You will find that each object is, in turn, calling its own update() method.