# Mocking Jdbc interfaces in spock

Tags: java, jdbc, mockito, spock, powermock

I am working on a tiny [framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3057526/#3057818) to wrap Database Stored Procedure calls named [`spwrap`](https://github.com/mhewedy/spwrap)

[Here's the code](https://github.com/mhewedy/spwrap/blob/master/src/test/groovy/spwrap/DAOTest.groovy#L287:L298):

```
@ConfineMetaClassChanges([CallableStatement])
def "Result of output parameter getInt throws SQLException" (){

    given:
        def sqlExceptionMsg = "exception happend while tring to call getInt"
        CallableStatement.metaClass.getObject = { int parameterIndex -> throw new SQLException(sqlExceptionMsg)}

    when:
        def custId = customerDao.createCustomer("Abdullah", "Mohammad")

    then:
        def e = thrown(CallException)
        e.cause == SQLException
        e.cause.message == sqlExceptionMsg
}
```

the method [`createCustomer`](https://github.com/mhewedy/spwrap/blob/master/src/test/java/spwrap/CustomerDAO.java#L23:L25) returns no reference to `CallableStatement`, however under the hood a `CallableStatement.getObject(int)` is being called, and I want to test the case where a `SQLException` is thrown.

I am trying to override the bahvaiour on the `CallableStatement.getObject(int)` class (since I have to reference to the used object by the framework - at least in this scenario)

The above test fails as it seems the `CallableStatement.getObject(int)` is not being changed. However when i use the `<<` it complains (and it should). How to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**:

Using `GroovyMock` doesn't help:

```
// test fails!
def "Calling interface methods calling JDBC Driver methods" (){
    given:
        CustomerDAO customerDAO2 = new DAO.Builder("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:customers", "sa", "").build().create(CustomerDAO);
        def callableStatement = GroovyMock(JDBCCallableStatement, global: true)
    when:
        customerDAO2.createCustomer("Abdullah", "Mohammad")
    then:
        1 * callableStatement.getObject(_ as Integer)
}
```

***Can I achieve this with other Mocking frameworks?***

Comment: Since I'm not entirely familiar with groovy metaclasses, I have a question: does altering metaclass of interface affects all implementations of that interface? Because if it's not (and I will expect it so, given Java proxying constraints), then code in this question does nothing to the actual jdbc driver implementation of `CallableStatement`.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for you not to use normal mocks or stubs but to fiddle with meta classes?

Comment: No, but i think mocks works with particular instance of the class, but this is not my case.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Spock isn't very powerful when it comes to Mocking static/final Java code. One of the workarounds I've taken to doing is placing any such method calls in their own method, which Spock should have no problem hooking into.

```
public class MyClass {
    //... stuff ...

    protected Object retrieveObject(int) throws SQLException {
        return CallableStatement.getObject(int)
    }
}

public class MyClassTest extends Specification {
def "Test example for wrapping unmockable method" (){
    given:
        MyClass example = new MyClass();
    when:
        example.callMethod("Parameters")
    then:
        1 * example.retrieveObject(_) >> { throw new SQLException(sqlExceptionMsg) }
}
}
```