# What exactly are frameworks and libraries?

Tags: frameworks, libraries

I looked on the Internet for an explanation, but I am still a relative beginner and couldn't understand the jargon.

What, in simple, lay terms, are frameworks (such as React.js, Angular.js, and Vue.js) and what are libraries (such as Node.js and jQuery)? Why are they so important? Should I learn more than just one of those?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Framework vs. Toolkit vs. Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057526/framework-vs-toolkit-vs-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Library**
Imagine that you need a specific code to convert datetime from year/month/day to day/month/year ok?
Are you already. thought if someone in the world already makes it? so, if someone. already did it you and download it and use it as a library

**Framework**
Imagine that you are a bank and you need many many many libraries from the same maintainer because. you. want to manage and. validate one unique technology, these many libraries do many things to build an entry/big application, like a mobile app, web app and etc.

**Example image**
You have the `framework` that will have MANY programmed codes to help you build your app and inside your `app` you have many `libraries` that is programmed codes for specific things.
[image]

I guess this link can help you https://medium.com/@i.e.rahul/eli5-platform-vs-framework-vs-library-154539de8b

Comment: Thank you, Italo Jose!

Comment: if it solved your question, please, mark it as solved to help the stack overflow "question search engine"