# External Sort Java

Tags: java, sorting, external-sorting

Is there a specific reason why Java does not have an in-built external sort algorithm implemented ?

Comment: (A short note what external sorting *is* would have been helpful, imho)

Comment: Don't you think the runtime library is big enough yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the JDK contains only the mostly used components.

It is the same thing with any external framework content. Why isn't it directly built-in ?

Simply because it doesn't need to be built-in. And because it's not developed by the same people.

But still you can use an external framework, or a library which will help you with that.

---

**Resources :**

- [code.google.com - externalsortinginjava](http://code.google.com/p/externalsortinginjava/)

Comment: Quick question: how do you differentiate between what does into part of a framework and what goes into libraries

Comment: You can check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724438/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-library-and-a-framework

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any modern language has external sorting built-in. Usually, it's just not part of the scope of a programming language. Also, think of embedded (or specialized) devices that have limited (or no) external memory, only RAM. Language features such as external sorting would be purposeless.

Comment: Well, so would be file IO in general on those devices, that point isn't very convincing ;-). But agreed that it is well out of scope for a general programming framework.

Comment: I don't think any language *ever* has external sorting built-in.

Comment: @Chris SQL has external sort built in - which is another reason java doesn't need it.