# STL library vs JCF framework

Tags: java, c++, collections, stl, terminology

Why is the STL considered a library, but the JCF a framework? What exactly is it in their respective designs that causes/justifies this distinction? Can you give a code example that illustrates this?

Comment: I think, with a library your code is using the library, whereas with a framework the framework uses your code. Roughly. With a framework your code has to *fit in* with the framework, it has to be adapted to the framework and mostly restricted to what the framework supports.

Comment: If I pass a Comparator to `std::sort`, isn't the STL also using my code?

Comment: I'm not sure where the dividing line is exactly. But it's a matter of degree of control inversion. With `std::sort` you're merely customizing a particular call of a library function, while with a framework you'd override some comparator function in a "Sorter" functor class and create an instance of that class, sort of?

Comment: Java uses a simple `Comparator` interface with a `compare` method. You pass an object of a class that implements that interface to `Collections.sort`... I really don't see any conceptual difference.

Comment: I believe "framework" is used as a buzzword here, were `framework` sounds *better designed* than a library, for example from the [Oracle Site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) - `..the best-known examples of collections frameworks are the C++ Standard Template Library (STL) and Smalltalk's collection hierarchy` so even Oracle considers the STL to be a "Collections Framework".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition by Martin Fowler:

> A **library** is essentially a set of functions that you can call, these
>   days usually organized into classes. Each call does some work and
>   returns control to the client.
>
> A **framework** embodies some abstract design, with more behavior built
>   in. In order to use it you need to insert your behavior into various
>   places in the framework either by subclassing or by plugging in your
>   own classes. The framework's code then calls your code at these
>   points.

More discussion can you find here:
[What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Comment: Do you have an example where the JCF call my code, but the "equivalent" STL example doesn't?