# what is the api for Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

Hi I am new to Java and Android.I am developing on android for past few days.Some terms that I often hear is API.Could some body please explain the meaning of API.What I understood while reading through some web sites is it is the collection of classes and interfaces.If that is true then what does it mean when we say API for Broadcast receiver or Activity.

My Second question is that Android uses some library for parsing JSON.The package for this is org.json.What is the framework ?

Hope some body could guide me in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: General rule-of-thumb: Two questions -> Two posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application programming interface (API) is a set of routines, data structures, object classes and/or protocols provided by libraries and/or operating system services in order to support the building of applications.

A good API makes it easier to develop a program by providing all the building blocks. A programmer then puts the blocks together.

To get [BrodcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in our app we need to extends the Base Classes and implement required method.

- What is [JSON Framework](http://www.mobileapplicationservices.com/json-framework.html)?
- Difference b/w [Framwork and Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)