# Java Collections: Framework Or a library?

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Java documentation says [The collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html)

Why is java collections called a framework and not a library?
Now I am more confused about what I can expect from a framework as to a library..

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/148747/738746

Comment: Is a cat a predator or a mammal?  Now apply the same reasoning to this question!

Comment: You shouldn't expect different things from a framework and a library.  I'd use them nearly synonymously.

Answer (score 2):

The following characteristics differentiate Frameworks from libraries:

inversion of control - In a framework, unlike in libraries or normal user applications, the overall program's flow of control is not dictated by the caller, but by the framework.

default behavior - A framework has a default behavior. This default behavior must actually be some useful behavior and not a series of no-ops.

extensibility - A framework can be extended by the user usually by selective overriding or specialized by user code providing specific functionality.

non-modifiable framework code - The framework code, in general, is not allowed to be modified. Users can extend the framework, but not modify its code.

Basically a framework is a type of a library whose behavior cannot be changed. For instance, you can extend class ArrayList or HashMap in java, but you cannot change the behavior of those classes.