# In the osx/ios world, what is a library and what is a framework?

Tags: ios, macos

I am learning development on `osx` and `ios`. So far, coding is ok. The most difficult is to handle all the files, all the configuration issues (of `xcode`), and so on. I thought hearing from a guru about libraries/frameworks would help me a lot!

I would like to know more about libraries and frameworks.

- What is a library, what is a framework (and what's the difference between them)?
- Where can I find a list of all the frameworks (of all the libraries?)? Or: what are the most important frameworks?
- What can I do without any framework?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library

Comment: Yes i know. But i thought There could be a more specific/precise answer for Apple technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is very well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Finding the right frameworks is half the fun coding with iOS. There are loads of lists out there and depending on what you are doing there are some frameworks that are very used. One great tool to look at is [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/). It can not only help you find frameworks but it also manages the frameworks in your project. Adding cocoapods in my opinion should be the fist thing you do in a project. All that said, my three favorite frameworks are:

- AFNetworking: To handle network requests.
- RestKit: To transform JSON into objects. (it's actually built on top of AFNetworking)
- SVProgressHUD: A lightweight progress HUD

Finally you can do everything without ever using an external framework but why would you recode something that is already coded and battle tested.

Comment: I thought AFNNetworking was a library...

Comment: As you can see in the response in the first link: "Mac OS X frameworks are just libraries"

Comment: Which doesnt mean that all libraries are frameworks...

Comment: True I should have been more exact.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, some informations about frameworks on OS X/iOS.

A framework on OS X/iOS is a bundle used to distribute shared resources, including library code, resource files, header files… [For more details see](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SoftwareProducts/SoftwareProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH206-TPXREF109)

A list of system frameworks available on OS X [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH210-BBCBEAJD)