# what is difference between library file and framework?

Tags: frameworks, libraries

I couldn't get clear idea in differences between framework and libraries, can you suggest your idea or refer me any website or article thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Doc is always a good place to start:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html

In sum, Frameworks are an Apple specific mechanism for packaging dynamic code in a well defined directory structure. Frameworks are a particular type of Bundle which allow for versioning, storing and loading resources (icons, string files). Dynamic libraries provide only the shared module (with the *.dylib extension).

Note, OS X supports both methods, but Frameworks provide a great deal of flexibility both in development, deployment and management and are usually the preferred choice.

Using Frameworks requires compiler/linker specific flags to properly use. You should consult the Clang/XCode documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The main difference between a framework and library is how we implement it.
For instance take React Library and Angular framework which is popular tool for frontend these days.
Library doesn't require us to follow certain structure of implementation.For example in React we just incorporate along with our JavaScript codes.
On the other hand Frameworks require certain structure of implementation as in case of Angular framework which is difficult to learn.