# Is Angular JS a library or a framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While going through on-line documents about `Angular JS` in some of the documents they have mentioned `Angular JS` is not Library it is `Frame Work` but in some website they have mentioned `Angular JS` is Library.

Which one is Correct?

Comment: frameworks create a skeleton for you to build your app; libraries give you functionality but are completely unopinionated about your app. Angular is definitely a framework

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Angular is a framework**

This is a direct quote from the [AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction)

> AngularJS is a structural framework for dynamic web apps. It lets you
>   use HTML as your template language and lets you extend HTML's syntax
>   to express your application's components clearly and succinctly.
>   Angular's data binding and dependency injection eliminate much of the
>   code you would otherwise have to write. And it all happens within the
>   browser, making it an ideal partner with any server technology.

This is just the introduction piece but it tells us that AngularJS is definitely a framework and not just a library.

**Define the differences**

**Library** performs specific, well-defined operations.

**Framework** is a skeleton where the application defines the "meat" of the operation by filling out the skeleton. The skeleton still has code to link up the parts but the most important work is done by the application.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library) question, please credit the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short answer from [AngularJS site FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

> Is AngularJS a library, framework, plugin or a browser extension?
>   AngularJS fits the definition of a framework the best, even though it's much more lightweight than a typical framework and that's why many confuse it with a library.
>
> AngularJS is 100% JavaScript, 100% client-side and compatible with
>   both desktop and mobile browsers. So it's definitely not a plugin or
>   some other native browser extension.