# What is the difference between a framework, a bundle and a library in iOS?

Tags: ios, frameworks, shared-libraries, bundle

I understand a little bit about the differences between a framework and library I. But why bundles? It will be great if someone can explain when to use which?

I have seen bundle in duplicate difference between library and framework, but not between library and bundle or bundle and framework.

Comment: Every framework is a bundle, but not all bundles are frameworks.  For example, an app is a bundle, but it isn't a framework.  Something is only a framework if its primary purpose is to provide the library inside (optionally with headers, related non-code resources, documentation, etc.).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Library? Static? Dynamic? Or Framework? Project inside another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331056/library-static-dynamic-or-framework-project-inside-another-project)