# Why is Spring called a framework and not a library?

Tags: spring, frameworks

I was wondering what could be the major difference between a library and framework. When can we use a library in our application and when can we go for a framework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking to search the documentation is off topic. Another why doesn't really exist.

Comment: This [same question appeared in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148747/831878) and it eventually got closed

Comment: This is more or less the same question as the broader https://stackoverflow.com/q/148747/831878 (closed question). Closing this as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

A framework is a skeleton of an application which provides general functionalities for the application. You just need to focus on the business logic part of the application. You implement your application by using the provided functionalities and APIs, also you can easily extend the framework by adding some functionalities and APIs. 
A library provides some functionalities, but it is not a skeleton of some kind of applications.
Commonly, a framework consists of many libraries.