# Tensorflow and keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am newbie on deep learning and it happens to me to confuse between Keras and tensorflow. knowing that tensorflow is a framework and Keras is a library, what is the difference between using these two deep learning tools.

Answer (score 3):

Keras purposes is to use a framework in backend like Tensorflow, Theano or CNTK in an easier way.

For example, create a simple convolutional model under Tensorflow can be hard.
While create the same model under keras is very instinctive.

The difference between Tensorflow/Theano/CNTK and Keras is the following :
Keras is a framework who use the functions of Tensorflow/Theano/CNTK.
So Keras needs one of them to do something.

Tensorflow/Theano/CNTK or other like coffee can do everything by themselves.
But, often, it's harder to develop a model with them.

Comment: You mean Keras is a library!

Comment: You can look at Panos's answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library
I think Keras is more likely a framework according to Panos's answer.

Comment: Since we can use keras on the top of Tf Teano... so it shouldn't be a framework