# Tensorflow vs OpenCV

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm new into the AI world, I've start doing some stuff using Python & OpenCV for face detection and so on. I know that with the implementation of some algorithms I can develop AI system using Python & OpenCV. So my question is : What is the position of Tensorflow here? Can I say Tensorflow is an alternative to OpenCV? as I can say Python is an alternative programming language to Java (for example).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The main difference is that TensorFlow is a framework for machine learning, and OpenCV is a library for computer vision. It can be a good start to check the link below to get a grasp for the difference between framework and library: [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

You can do image recognition with TensorFlow. Though it is suited for more general problems as well, such as: classification, clustering and regression.

I guess people downvoted because this question might be more relevant to: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @Emmet. It's more clearer now, especially the part of library vs framework.

Comment: My experience with downvotes is that they come more from an OP's unwillingness to google for 10 minutes before submitting a question. Or at least that seems to be the kind-of litmus test for the majority of downvotes I've seen.