# Front end frameworks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

can both bootstrap and reactJS co exist in one project?

Comment: You're confused in framework and library. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library).

Comment: woohhh thanks for that response @choz but I think that is too broad for me now to understand. I want to focus now on the frameworks mentioned above.

Comment: @Anthony Unfortunately SO is not a website to ask those kind of questions. SO is willing to help you in case of a bug or a problem with your code and when you already tried multiple solutions that do not work.

Comment: @Weedoze sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the following front-end roadmap will help you in your learning quest it gives you clear what to do next list :

[image]

Reference: [kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap)

Comment: thanks for this. This will definitely helps a lot