# difference between Javascript framework and Javascript library

Tags: javascript

I was searching for difference between Javascript libraries and javascript frameworks. AngularJS, DOJO, JQuery,Ext JS all these are javascript frameworks.
What comes under Javascript library? I know the question is quite simple for the UI developers but looking for the exact answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Answer (score 3):

> A JavaScript framework is an application framework written in JavaScript. It differs from a JavaScript library in its control flow a library offers functions to be called by its parent code, whereas a framework defines the entire application design.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_framework

A javascript framework is something that **sets up (designs)** your code for you (Flask uses templates to set up your code), and all a javascript library does is lets you **access functions** that make certain tasks in coding much easier to do (jQuery has a `.click()` function that is much easier to use when you click on a button).

A main difference is that a with a library, you use it **how you wish**. With a framework, you use it how the **framework wants you to**.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-JavaScript-framework-and-a-library

**List of javascript libraries:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries

Comment: I want to know the list of javascript libraries.

Comment: Sorry mine would be totally bad question, but i'm confused now as when i was referring the links u gave , in both the javascript framework link and javascript library links you mentioned above, there are AnuglarJS, React, JQuery etc mentioned as frameworks as well as library.

Comment: @user3684675 some could be both. For example, you could use bootstrap to completely set up your project (with the `div.container > div.row > div.col` method, or you could simply use the class `text-center` to center something. I don't really know much about those AngularJS and React, and jQuery is a library (I don't think it clasifies as a framework)

Comment: Think of it this way: A framework is the skeleton (like in your body) and a library is a function (like moving your arms)