# Is `react-dom` a library or a framework?

Tags: reactjs, frameworks

My understanding of the vital difference between a library and a framework is whether my application code uses the package code or the package runs my application code - otherwise called "inversion of control".

[image: Inversion of control]

It makes sense that `react` is a *UI library* since I can create a DOM interface (its representation).

But when I want to render it using `react-dom`, my application can only trigger a render (by calling `ReactDOM.render()`, state updates or forced updates) but it is upto `react-dom` to decide when to render it.

Since `react-dom` takes up the responsibility to render the UI, does it qualify as a framework? And if not, please give an explanation so I can clear my understanding of the topic.

*PS: Perhaps SO is not the best place for this question. If you know a better on, do let me know.*

Comment: Does the distinction matter?

Comment: I want to satisfy my curiosity and so it matters to me. It's possible that such classifications hold no value to some people since they add no productive value to anything and it's just as likely that some people genuinely need such labels for various reasons. Whether a question matters or not seems like a _harsh remark_ more than anything else.

Comment: Every comment on this platform, no matter how benign, seems interpreted as harsh nowadays.

Comment: Interesting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66561426/11792577

Answer (score -1):

ReactDom is **not** both of a library and a framework. A single piece of code or method cannot be considered as a library or framework. To be a library it contains many methods and to be a framework it contains many library.

So, you'll need to understand what is [library and framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)? And if you have a question on react itself as if it's a library or framework, then read these blogs: [medium](https://medium.com/@_cmdv_/react-is-not-a-framework-e25c28dcd78) and [dev.to](https://dev.to/renannobile/why-is-react-a-library-and-not-a-simple-framework-1mle) - you'll find it stating react is a library.

But I would say it is a framework because it includes many library. And many other blogs indicates it as a framework as well. To conclude, this is huge opinion based result for what you understand it as a library or a framework.