# React is considered as a library and Angular is considered as a framework. Why so?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, frameworks

Please someone answer by justifying the definition of library and framework.
 "**Your code calls library whereas framework calls your code.**"

Comment: With React you keep writing methods you don't call yourself, so that already meets the mentioned definition of a framework. I'd say that a framework is a special kind of library, and that both Angular and React are frameworks. I guess you also see it that way, so the real question to me is, who claimed that React is not a framework?

Comment: this all sounds very opinionated :p

Comment: @Chris G React is a full-featured dom manipulation and state engine. Looks like framework. On the other hand, there is not a strictly set Model and Controller in React. It is not MVC rather only 'view' in MVC. One can choose whatever fits one's needs. The creator likes to call it library.  The question is : where to draw the line?

Answer (score 5):

React cannot be considered a library given provided, absolutely correct, and only one that makes any sense definition of the difference between framework and library.

The library is just a set of methods/functions.

The framework provides a frame for work, it requires the code to be written in a certain way.

Considering the above, React obviously is the framework. Very complex, very opinionated framework.

Why it has been promoted as a library?

IMHO because promoters of React are cheap manipulators who wanted to steal the popularity of jQuery - the most popular JavaScript library.

Good [library vs framework article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library-bd133054023f/). The author uses jQuery as an example of a library and Vue as an example of a framework. Probably, just in order to not tease geese. But Vue code from provided example is almost similar to analogic React code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is basically related to use case of both the technologies, as React is called as a library because of its behavior of easy to fit into any js environment and doesn't bound user to use things React way, while one the other hand Angular is complete MVC (Model View Controller) architecture, and restrict user to follow its pattern of framework.