# What is the certain difference between libraries and frameworks ? Especially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frameworks, libraries

I was making research about frameworks as a beginner JavaScript learner and I saw people also use libraries so I didn't understand what is the difference between them and why people use these libraries and frameworks ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [What is the difference between a framework and a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148747)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Framework means It is use with main programming languages to short the code
Example :- if we built API with only node js then it will take to effort and if we use Express then it will easy to make an API

Library means it will use of a particular area means if we want to generate token then we use only one library if we want to make another like to generate unique id so we want to use another library

Framework is use with whole language but library use for particular area.